# Inverting bars on d3.js bar chart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I'm just getting started with D3.js and am having a problem with getting the bars horizontally lined up. Currently they come out pointing downwards.

```
var jsonRectangles = [
  { "x_axis": 10,  "y_axis": 0, "height": 65,  "width":20, "color": "green" },
  { "x_axis": 40,  "y_axis": 0, "height": 80,  "width":20, "color": "purple" },
  { "x_axis": 70,  "y_axis": 0, "height": 100, "width":20, "color": "orange" },
  { "x_axis": 100, "y_axis": 0, "height": 50,  "width":20, "color": "brown" },
  { "x_axis": 130, "y_axis": 0, "height": 66,  "width":20, "color": "black" },
  { "x_axis": 160, "y_axis": 0, "height": 68,  "width":20, "color": "red" }];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 100);

var rectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
        .data(jsonRectangles)
       .enter()
        .append("rect");

var rectangleAttributes = rectangles
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.weight); })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

Answer (score 2):

The (0,0) coordinate in an SVG is in the top left corner, so your y coordinates are "reversed" in the sense that they are counted from the top. This means that you have to position your bars so that they start at y position that you want to show and extend to the axis. Your code should look something like this.

```
rectangles.attr("y", function (d) { return (heightOfGraph - y(d.height)); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.height); });
```

On a general note, you don't need to save `rectangleAttributes` in a variable -- it will be exactly the same as `rectangles`.

Comment: Hey,can u check my latest question? I kinda got into a similar situation,but coudnnt resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In D3, 0 on the y coordinate is at the top rather than the bottom. You need to fist move the bars down to where you want the y axis origin to be, then move the bars up by their height to position them correctly.

Here's a rough solution though that hopefully you'll be able to work with (see the comments for the bits that have changed):

```
var jsonRectangles = [
  { "x_axis": 10, "y_axis": 0, "height": 65, "width":20, "color" : "green" },
  { "x_axis": 40, "y_axis": 0, "height": 80, "width":20, "color" : "purple" },
  { "x_axis": 70, "y_axis": 0, "height": 100, "width":20, "color" : "orange" },
  { "x_axis": 100, "y_axis": 0, "height": 50, "width":20, "color" : "brown" },
  { "x_axis": 130, "y_axis": 0, "height": 66, "width":20, "color" : "black" },
  { "x_axis": 160, "y_axis": 0, "height": 68, "width":20, "color" : "red" }];

// height of the visualisation - used to translate the bars
var viz_height = 100;

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 500)
                                    // set using viz_height rather than a fixed number
                                    .attr("height", viz_height);

var rectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
                             .data(jsonRectangles)
                             .enter()
                             .append("rect");

var rectangleAttributes = rectangles
                          .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                          // move the bars to the bottom of the chart (using
                          // viz_height), then move them back up by the height of
                          // the bar which moves them into palce
                          .attr("y", function (d) { return viz_height - y(d.height); })
                          .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.height); })
                          .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
                          .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

[image]

Comment: `y` is a function which was provided in the original question (but no source given). It's a function which gives a position based on the datum's `height`. The simplest implementation would be `function y(height) { return height; }`